# Approach to Handling Stationarity in Multi-dimensional Time Series Forecasting with AutoARIMA

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stationarity, statsmodels

I am working on a time series forecasting project for a meal delivery service that operates in multiple cities. The company has several fulfillment centers across these cities for dispatching meal orders to their customers. My goal is to develop a demand forecasting model to predict the number of orders for the upcoming weeks at each fulfillment center.

The dataset includes information on the number of orders, along with additional features such as center ID, meal ID, city, and region. Since each center handles multiple meal IDs and operates in different cities and regions, I understand the importance of stationarity for accurate forecasting.Following are the sample data

[image: Train]

[image: Center]

I plan to use the ARIMA model from the statsmodels library in Python for forecasting and using center_id,   city_code,region_code,center_type as an extra regressor. However, considering the multi-dimensional nature of the dataset (multiple centers, meal IDs, cities, and regions), I'm unsure about how to approach stationarity.

Should I make each center, meal ID, city, and region stationary separately before applying ARIMA? Or make whole data stationary? I am lost if i make each center, meal ID, city, and region stationary separately then how will i decide the AR,MA parameter? There are 77 centers and 55 meals.

What would be the best approach to achieve stationarity for each of these dimensions individually?

Any insights or suggestions on how to handle stationarity in this context, particularly using the statsforecast approach, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you could try to use MLForecast library. Maybe StatsForecast could do what you want. Give a chance to that lib.

https://nixtlaverse.nixtla.io/mlforecast/index.html

It's possible to preprocess input data, etc...

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment 
than an answer. You could [edit] to expand it, perhaps by giving a 
summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: I have reviewed Statesforecast, and nowhere did I see that this algorithm requires data to be stationary. Do you have any information about this?